# Jenkins hosted on Windows OS to run shell scripts after build

Tags: java, windows, shell, jenkins

I am trying to run a jenkins job which has a post deployment activity of running a few shell script commands. Jenkins is hosted on a windows OS. Can anyone tell me how Jenkins can connect to the Solaris environment on another machine and execute the shell script? Is this possible?

I am trying to build a Java WAR file on windows and then deploy it on tomcat on Solaris machine.

The WAR file is built. I need to write a shell script to copy that WAR file to Solaris machine.

Does anyone know how to integrate [https://wiki.jenkins-
ci.org/display/JENKINS/XShell+Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/XShell+Plugin)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [Artifact Deployer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ArtifactDeployer+Plugin). It can copy files to a remote location and it does support Windows.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question, yes, Jenkins can execute shell scripts on remote hosts.  The most straightforward method that comes to mind is the Jenkins SSH Plugin, or the [Jenkins Publish Over SSH Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin).  Either of those plugins will allow you to execute arbitrary commands over Secure Shell (SSH) to a host that supports SSH (like Solaris).

For your specific use case, however, it may be better to use a more specialized development plugin, such as the Deploy Plugin.  Especially if you're using Maven to build your project in Jenkins, Apache publishes a Maven plugin that can automate deployment to Tomcat.